# Get friend without friend app user with FQL or Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Now I get random 19 friend in my facebook with fql query : `SELECT uid, pic_square, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (   SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() ) ORDER BY rand() limit 19`, 
But now I don't know, how to get 19 friends not in `friendappuser`.

Answer (score 2):

I already found anwser for my question:

```
SELECT uid, pic_square, name 
FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend 
WHERE uid1 = me())  AND is_app_user = 0 ORDER BY rand() limit 19
```